# How to prove the convergence of the integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to prove the convergence or divergence of the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x\sin{x}}{x^3+4}}$$
I understand that it is necessary to intoduce $g(x)$ so that $0\le f(x) \le g(x)$ and to prove the convergence (divergence) of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}{g(x)}$. 
But what $g(x)$ should I take?

Comment: it is continuous on any $[0,a]$ and $\le \frac{x\times 1}{x^3+0}=\frac 1{x^2}$ which behaves good at infinity.

Comment: $$\left|\frac{x\sin x}{x^3+4}\right| \le \frac{x}{x^3+4} \le \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2}, & x > 1\\ \frac14, &x \le 1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x \sin{x}}{x^3+4}}$ converges or diverges the same as $\displaystyle \int_{\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}{\frac{x \sin{x}}{x^3+4}}\;\;$ (*why?*)
- for $x \ge 1\,$: $\;\;\displaystyle \left|\frac{x \sin{x}}{x^3+4}\right| \le \frac{x}{x^3+4} \le \frac{x}{x^3} = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: Why the same as?

Comment: @PashaMinigun Because $\,\int_{0}^{\infty} = \int_{0}^{1} + \int_{\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\,$ and the first term on the RHS is some (finite) constant equal to the definite integral of a function that is continuous on $[0,1]\,$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The function $\displaystyle f(x)=\Big\lvert\frac{x\sin x}{x^3+4}\Big\rvert$ satisfies
$$
0\le f(x)\le \le g(x)=\frac{x}{x^3+4} \qquad \forall x\ge0.
$$
Notice, using the change of variables $t=x^{-1}$, that
$$
\int_1^\infty g(x)\,dx=\int_1^0-g\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)t^{-2}\,dt=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+4t^3}\,dt.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx=\int_0^1g(x)\,dx+\int_1^\infty g(x)\,dx=\int_0^1\left(\frac{x}{x^3+4}+\frac{1}{1+4x^3}\right)\,dx
$$
which shows that the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ is convergent, and so is the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$.
Therefore, the given integral is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

On $[2,+\infty)$ the function $\frac{x}{x^3+4}$ is decreasing towards zero; $\sin(x)$ has a bounded primitive and $\left|\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^3+4}\right|$ is bounded by $1$ on $[0,2]$. It follows that your integral is convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).